# Struggling to get multiple input fields value with the same name in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller

[My input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGl3s.png)

[image: Some JS to populate phone number fields]

[image: In my Controller only first input is showing?]

My question is how can i get all values from Name="phone" fields

[image: Should get these values, only getting first value]

> JS

```
<script>
    $(function(){

        $(document.body).on('click', '.changeType' ,function(){
            $(this).closest('.phone-input').find('.type-text').text($(this).text());
            $(this).closest('.phone-input').find('.type-input').val($(this).data('type-value'));
        });

        $(document.body).on('click', '.btn-remove-phone' ,function(){
            $(this).closest('.phone-input').remove();
        });


        $('.btn-add-phone').click(function(){

            var index = $('.phone-input').length + 1;

            $('.phone-list').append(''+
                '<div class="input-group phone-input">'+
                '<input type="number" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="(999) 999 9999" />'+
                '<span class="input-group-btn">'+
                '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-remove-phone" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>'+
                '</span>'+
                '</div>'
            );

        });

    });</script>
```

> HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-10">

                        <div class="phone-list">

                            <div class="input-group phone-input">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    </span>
                                <input type="number" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="(999) 999 9999"  required=""/>
                            </div>

                        </div>


                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block btn-add-phone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add Phone</button>
                    </div>
```

> Controller

```
   @PostMapping("/applicant")
   public String saveApplicantToDb(
       @Valid @ModelAttribute Applicant applicant, 
       @RequestParam("phone") int[] phone
   ) {
        if (phone!= null)
        System.out.println(phone.length);

        _applicantRepository.save(applicant);

        return "applicant";
    }
```

Comment: Please paste your code here as text, not as an image. It's very hard to make it out.

Comment: Edited if u should provide with more code let me know please help guys) really appreciate it))

Comment: @Aliy please edit the answer. I can't see the HTML.

Comment: Edited @Mureinik

Comment: Was the answer to this found? i have a similar problem. @Aliy

Comment: I have debugged to the point that I have realized the receiving data type was array of string not int so what was ur problem send me I will try to help @MakamuEvans

Answer (score 0):

You are using multiple input number fields with the same name "phone" which is right, no problem with this and it should reflect back in the input @Param("phone"), but you have to make sure that the phone inputs must be of type integer for example your placeholder is totally incorrect (999) 999 9999. also the new added phone is not an integer. So make sure they are integers

Comment: I have found solution for this issue, thanks for replying

Comment: You are correct it is sending me String[] type of array

Answer (score 0):

The problem was name should match with your model attribute
However i was expecting int[] type of array from view but it was sending me String[] type of array problem solved and also make sure your JS code populating your input fields correctly [especially name='field_name'] should match to the attribute of your model. Check your it on browser -> inspect and collapse divs and see input field name